# Can shell (command line) display GUI generated commands?

Tags: command-line, gui

Can the shell (command line) display  GUI  generated  commands?

Example:

1. Go to: `Applications => Programming => Netbeans`
2. When Netbeans starts I want to see in shell `$ netbeans / gksu netbeans`
3. (Edit) When I doing with netbeans svn update I want to see this in shell

Edit:
 Netbeans only example

Thanks

Comment: What would you like to do? Run a script when an application is started?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the Netbeans menu item run `netbeans` in a visible terminal window:

1. Right-click the **Applications** menu and then click **Edit Menus**.
2. On the **Programming** menu, select **Netbeans** and then click **Properties**.
3. Change the **Type** to **Application in Terminal** and then click **Close**.

It might take a minute for the menu to be updated with the new settings. If you're impatient, try running `killall gnome-panel` to force a reload.

Tip: To make the terminal window stay open after Netbeans has closed, use the menu editor again to change the Netbeans menu item's command from `netbeans` to `sh -c 'netbeans ; bash'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **top** or **htop** to display running services.
You can do a search for netbeans in there?